# why mysql execute sql need convert character set several times

Tags: mysql

I mean that when the Mysql excute a sql,the fist step is to convert `character_set_client` to `character_set_connection`, then `character_set_connection` will be converted to a specific character_set（beside on table character set)。
mysql execute sql need convert character set several times, why it is designed like this.

Comment: Maybe the server instance settings are set incorrectly in configuration file my.ini? when everything is set correctly none charset/collatoin adjusting needed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.